# Python Get Date In Future (x) Days, And Hours Left To Date?

Tags: python, date, timer, countdown

How can I get date + time in the future from now by days? in this format: 10/08/2013 9:50 PM (dd/mm/yyyy) and also I would like Time left to date in hours for this new future date?

Comment: 10/08/2013 is future? :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a `datetime` in combination with a `timedelta` object.

Like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.now()
td = timedelta(days=4)
# your calculated date
my_date = dt + td
```